# http redirect and change pool

Tags: f5, big-ip, irule

My irule is;

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
if {[HTTP::uri] starts_with "/xxxx"} {
HTTP::redirect https://example.com/yyyy
}
if {[HTTP::uri] starts_with "/zzzz"} {
HTTP::redirect https://example.com/bbbb
}
}
```

This works as we expect it to. We have a virtual server on https://example.com that has a pool (called say poolA, with a node called nodeA).

What we want to do is modify the exisiting irule so that it not only does a redirect but also changes the pool. I tried the following;

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  if {[HTTP::uri] starts_with "/xxxx"} {
  HTTP::redirect https://example.com/yyyy
  poolB
}
if {[HTTP::uri] starts_with "/zzzz"} {
HTTP::redirect https://example.com/bbbb
poolB
}
}
```

NodeB in poolB has a webserver on it and is listening on the correct port and has a website that matches the direction URL.

If I go to https://example.com/xxxx in Chrome, I get the following error;

> error too many redirects

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a switch in this case. If you are redirecting, you don't need to set the pool because that request won't proceed to a pool member.

```
when HTTP_REQUEST {
  switch -glob [string tolower [HTTP::uri]] {
    "/xxxx*" { HTTP::redirect https://example.com/yyyy }
    "/zzzz*" { HTTP::redirect https://example.com/bbbb }
    "/yyyy*" -
    "/bbbb*" { pool poolB }
  }
}
```

We have a lot of great tutorials on DevCentral. Here's the [first article](https://devcentral.f5.com/articles/-the101-irules-101-introduction-to-programming-amp-tcl) in a ten-part series on iRules called The101.